# Intraweb Template does not load the Pictures

Tags: templates, delphi-xe5, intraweb

I created an Intraweb template with single colored boxes.
When i now try to run my Intraweb Application, i can see the different slices of my template but the pictures wasn't loaded. I put it in the win32/debug folder lile its said in the documentation but the pictures are never loaded.
Any suggestions?
Thank you
Chris
[Edit]
Piece of my Html Code
`<div id="Tabelle_01">
    <div id="Test-01">
        <img src="Bilder/Test_01.jpg" width="454" height="127" alt="">
                {%IWRegion1%}
    </div>`
[Solution]
Adding next to the "Templates" Folder a Folder "wwwroot" and adding the Images to it and then it works.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You did not say which version of Intraweb you are using, but in current versions Templates go in the (application)\Templates directory.  Templates only modify the form, so pictures go wherever the form expects them to be.  ex: your wwwroot  (Application)\wwwroot.

In your case (guessing) "debug\templates" and "debug\wwwroot".

Please post your code.

Dan

Comment: I Use the newest Intraweb Version 14.0.52.
Do you want to see the template html code?  
the folder "debug\wwwroot" does not exist. Shall i create it?
The Html Template expect the Pictures to be in "...Templates\Bilder"  
`<div id="Tabelle_01">
 <div id="Test-01">
  <img src="Bilder/Test_01.jpg" width="454" height="127" alt="">
                {%IWRegion1%}
 </div>`  
(I hope that this is the code you wanted.)  
This is the way i want to adress the Pictures. In my Program i only add a iwRegion to the Form. 


Chris

Comment: ... And I added an TIWTemplateProcessorHTML ofcourse with the path to my Template

Comment: If you are running your exe out of win32\debug then the exe will look for your application folder as win32\debug\wwwroot by default.  It will look for your templates in win32\debug\templates.  If you specified the templates directory I think that should be OK, it's just not the default.  Your other files are expected in the application directory (wwwroot under your application).  I understand earlier versions were different but your version should do it this way (I'm running 14.0.45). I think you are looking in debug\wwwroot\Bilder for the jpg but I will check (or you can test).

Comment: This should help:  [IW 14 migration tips](http://docs.atozed.com/docs.dll/development/Migrating%20to%20IntraWeb%20XIV.html).  FWIW, it's just fact that IW is absolutely great but the documentation not so much many times.

Comment: Adding the "wwwroot" folder did the Trick.
Thank you very much.
Chris

Comment: Chris, another support area is the official [Intraweb support forum](https://forums.embarcadero.com/forum.jspa?forumID=93) on Embarcadero's site.  The AToZed people are there and follow up.  I like answering questions but this SO stuff is nuts.  I've been helping on a number of forums for 30 years.  This answer, even though you indicated it solved your problem, was downvoted by someone without even indicating a reason.  I don't need to participate in that kind of environment.  If you have additional questions, check in on the support forum.